# Return List from generic method via reflection error on Entry Point not found and Count

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, generic-list

I would like to return a List of entities via reflection.

It is not working in my project code but is working in a sandbox project. I am at a loss as to what is different between the two is. It is difficult to tear the project apart to find out why. Hopefully the following information will help someone point out a solution.

### Project code not working

The following is a watch of my not working project code. Pardon the wide printscreens.

Different screen shots of different branches of the same result. My items are there but I cannot access them in a internal/public way. See the other errors.

**[click for larger - items listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dS7A.png)**
[image]

**[click for larger - error on List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p78MN.png)**
[image]

**[click for larger - entry point not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNWkL.png)**
[image]

### Working Sandbox

The following is an example of my WORKING sandbox.

**Console**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.Replace("file:///", "").Replace("/", "\\")), "ClassLibrary1.dll");

        AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("some");
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
        assemblyName.CodeBase = fullPath;
        Assembly assembly = dom.Load(assemblyName);

        Type superclass = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.MySuperClass");
        Type superentity = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.MySuperEntity");

        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(superclass, new object[]{"Hello"});
        MethodInfo m = superclass.GetMethod("GetList", new Type[] {typeof (string)});
        MethodInfo g = m.MakeGenericMethod(superentity);
        var x = g.Invoke(instance, new object[] {"HelloEntity" });

    }
}
```

**ClassLibrary1.Class1.cs**

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class MySuperEntity : MyBaseEntity
    {
        public MySuperEntity() {}

        public MySuperEntity(string title) : base(title) {}
    }

    public class MyBaseEntity
    {
        public MyBaseEntity() {}

        public MyBaseEntity(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class MySuperClass : MyBaseClass {}

    public class MyBaseClass
    {
        public List<T> GetList<T>(string msg) where T : MyBaseEntity
        {
            return new List<T>
            {
                Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { "One " + msg }) as T,
                Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { "Two " + msg }) as T,
                Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { "Three " + msg }) as T
            };
        }
    }
}
```